# Unable to add time to current time

Tags: python, python-datetime

```
start_time=datetime.time(9,00)
new_time=starttime+datetime(0,50) # I want new time as 9.50
```

But this throws me an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Answer (score 3):

please try the below python script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta 
time = datetime(2013, 5, 31, 03, 00, 00)###or you can use time = datetime.datetime.now() 

diff = timedelta(seconds = 60)

final_time = time + diff
print final_time
```

Comment: thanks.. this seems to work.. i dont want to use time.now() cuz i have to update the time everytime i add a task (time is not taken from systime; it is defined by me)

Answer (score -1):

We can overload the operator, to do the above functionality, Please check the below code

```
class Mytime(datetime.time):
    def __add__(self,b):
        res = (self.hour*60+self.minute)+(b.hour*60+b.minute)
        return Mytime(res/60,res%60)

start_time = Mytime(9,0)
next_time = start_time+Mytime(9,0)
```